# Is combining row and col in the same div considered a bad practice?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

As the title already says, is combining row and col in the same div bad considered a bad practice and what are the side effects?

```
<div class="row col">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the specs of `col` & `row` based on the Bootstrap style sheet.

```
.col {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.col {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

If you will observe the combinations of these, the flex items does not appear to change that much except maybe for the padding introduced by the parent `col`. I would not advise doing this as it is not documented in Bootstrap's Grid System, but at the end of the day, these are just CSS classes that can eventually be overriden.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row col">
  <div class="col">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="col">flex item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="col">flex item 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example how on how it differs:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="font-weight-light">
      Row and col seperated
    </h3>
    <div class="row border border-primary">
      Row
      <div class="col border border-secondary">
        Col
        <div class="row border border-success">
          Row
          <div class="col border border-danger">
            Col
            <div class="row border border-danger">
              Row
              <div class="col border border-warning">
                Col
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="font-weight-light">
      Row and col combined
    </h3>
    <div class="row col border border-primary">
      Row Col
      <div class="row col border border-success">
        Row Col
        <div class="row col border border-danger">
          Row Col
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```